# PHP: Get all Commit Messages of Remote Repository

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse all the Git Commit Messages of a Remote Repository.
So far I have:

```
exec('git rev-parse --verify HEAD 2> /dev/null', $output);
$hash = $output[0];
exec("git show $hash", $output);
var_dump(exec('git fetch --all; git log origin/master', $output));
```

When I use the same commands in console it works just fine, showing me all the Commit Messages.

However once I try it in PHP, it only shows me "Initial Commit" and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you need to dump is not returned by the `exec()` function, it's in `$output`.

Instead of your last line, try

```
exec('git fetch --all; git log origin/master', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You are absolutely correct! I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I can